# WinCE device - change keyboard input method

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

We have a Casio DT-X8 scanners that we are using in our company. They run .NET Framework 3.5 and WindowsCE 5.0

I have developed an app for them to suit our needs. The keypad on those scanners is the old mobile phone style, so a number 2 would be the number 2 but also ABC and abc. You switch between modes using the F8 button on the scanner. We have textboxes in the application that requires either a text input or a number input. It is sometimes time consuming to switch between the modes using the F8.

My question is, is there a way to set the input method through the app? I am already using the core.dll file to set the correct date and time on the scanner, so is it also possible to do similar with the input method?

I have searched google and stackoverlow but couldn't find anything that relates to my question. Many problems were to do with controlling the language input, but not the actual input type.

I am not looking for a complete code as that I can do myself. I just need some directions as to what to look for and how to tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this feature is specific for that device.
Windows CE provides a way to change the software keyboard (look for Software Input Panel or SIP in the documentation), but does not apply to HW keyboards.
Do you have any "companion" app that can do this? If you have you know, at least, that it's possible to do it in SW.
If the HW manufacturer provides his own SDK that would be the first place where I would check for such a feature.
You may also have a look at the keybd_gen API in CE, this can be used to generate an emulated pressure of the F8 key. But I'm not too confident that this will work, since the key may be managed inside the keybd driver or at a lever lower than the one affected by that API and, in any case, it may be tricky to keep track of the keyboard state if the user presses that key when not running your app.